# How can I compare the equality of values within a dataframe to return a vector of 1s and 0s

Tags: r

I am working on a dataframe like this.

```
illness1<- c(1,2,2,3,3,5,1,7,8,3)
illness2<- c("a", "d", "c", "b", "e", "a", "d", "c", "b", "e")
datacode1<- 1:10
datacode2<- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
patient_id<- 1:10
diseasecode<- 1:10

df<- data.frame(patient_id, illness1, illness2, icd, datacode1, datacode2)
```

This gives me a dataframe like this.

```
    patient_id illness1 illness2 diseasecode datacode1 datacode2
 1:          1        1        a   1         1         a
 2:          2        2        d   2         2         b
 3:          3        2        c   3         3         c
 4:          4        3        b   4         4         d
 5:          5        3        e   5         5         e
 6:          6        5        a   6         6         f
 7:          7        1        d   7         7         g
 8:          8        7        c   8         8         h
 9:          9        8        b   9         9         i
10:         10        3        e  10        10         j
```

Each diseasecode represents a particular disease, and the datacode1 and datacode2 are the datacode that correspond to the disease. Let's say diseasecode "1" is hypertension, then hypertension will be represented by datacodes "1" and "a". That means the patient in the first row has hypertension, because he has "1" and "a" in his illness 1/2.

Moreover, the patient in row 6 & 7 also has hypertension, this is because row 7 has "1" in illness1 and row 6 has "a" in illness2

What I am trying to do is to generate a 10L vector in this case with 1 and 0, 1 meaning that the patient in that row has hypertension or any other disease in the dataframe.

What I would expect is:

```
   patient_id illness1 illness2 diseasecode datacode1 datacode2 diseasecode1 diseasecode2 diseasecode3 diseasecode4 diseasecode5 diseasecode6 diseasecode7
1           1        1        a           1         1         a            1            0            0            0            0            0            0
2           2        2        d           2         2         b            0            1            0            1            0            0            0
3           3        2        c           3         3         c            0            1            1            0            0            0            0
4           4        3        b           4         4         d            0            1            1            0            0            0            0
5           5        3        e           5         5         e            0            0            1            0            1            0            0
6           6        5        a           6         6         f            1            0            0            0            1            0            0
7           7        1        d           7         7         g            1            0            0            1            0            0            0
8           8        7        c           8         8         h            0            0            1            0            0            0            1
9           9        8        b           9         9         i            0            1            0            0            0            0            0
10         10        3        e          10        10         j            0            0            1            0            1            0            0
   diseasecode8 diseasecode9 diseasecode10
1             0            0             0
2             0            0             0
3             0            0             0
4             0            0             0
5             0            0             0
6             0            0             0
7             0            0             0
8             0            0             0
9             1            0             0
10            0            0             0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
illness1<- c(1,2,2,3,3,5,1,7,8,3)
illness2<- c("a", "d", "c", "b", "e", "a", "d", "c", "b", "e")
datacode1<- 1:10
datacode2<- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
patient_id<- 1:10
diseasecode<- 1:10

df<- data.frame(patient_id, illness1, illness2, diseasecode, datacode1, datacode2)
codes <- df %>% dplyr::select(datacode1, datacode2) %>% distinct()

for(i in 1:nrow(codes)){
  df[[paste0("diseasecode", codes$datacode1[i])]] <- ifelse(
    illness1 == codes[i,1] | illness2 == codes[i,2], 1, 0)
}
df
#>    patient_id illness1 illness2 diseasecode datacode1 datacode2 diseasecode1
#> 1           1        1        a           1         1         a            1
#> 2           2        2        d           2         2         b            0
#> 3           3        2        c           3         3         c            0
#> 4           4        3        b           4         4         d            0
#> 5           5        3        e           5         5         e            0
#> 6           6        5        a           6         6         f            1
#> 7           7        1        d           7         7         g            1
#> 8           8        7        c           8         8         h            0
#> 9           9        8        b           9         9         i            0
#> 10         10        3        e          10        10         j            0
#>    diseasecode2 diseasecode3 diseasecode4 diseasecode5 diseasecode6
#> 1             0            0            0            0            0
#> 2             1            0            1            0            0
#> 3             1            1            0            0            0
#> 4             1            1            0            0            0
#> 5             0            1            0            1            0
#> 6             0            0            0            1            0
#> 7             0            0            1            0            0
#> 8             0            1            0            0            0
#> 9             1            0            0            0            0
#> 10            0            1            0            1            0
#>    diseasecode7 diseasecode8 diseasecode9 diseasecode10
#> 1             0            0            0             0
#> 2             0            0            0             0
#> 3             0            0            0             0
#> 4             0            0            0             0
#> 5             0            0            0             0
#> 6             0            0            0             0
#> 7             0            0            0             0
#> 8             1            0            0             0
#> 9             0            1            0             0
#> 10            0            0            0             0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>